# CONCAT column with IF condition and WHERE condition

Tags: sql, mariadb

I have a table with two columns - APPLICATION and SOURCE.

I need to append a STRING to the value in APPLICATION column IF the APPLICATION column does not already include that STRING. I need to do this WHERE SOURCE is a certain value. So not the entire table.

EX: Where SOURCE = 'string1', CONCAT 'string2' to APPLICATION IF APPLICATION does not include 'string2'.

FYI - Values in Application look like this 'apple,banana,cookie' where there are no spaces. If string2 is 'cookie', then I need a command to recognize 'cookie' in that value and skip that column.

SAMPLE:
TABLE NAME: table_1
COLUMNS: application, sourcetb

WHERE SOURCE = 'acct', 'credit', 'mortgage' or 'loan'
IF application DOES NOT have 'CMS' then append 'CMS'. Otherwise, if it has 'CMS' do nothing.

So if SOURCE value = 'MMA,CMS,ABC', do nothing since it includes 'CMS'. If SOURCE value = 'CBS,ABC,NBC' then append ',CMS' -> 'CBS,ABC,NBC,CMS'. OF COURSE THIS IS ONLY WHERE SOURCE = 'acct', 'credit', 'mortgage' or 'loan'.

Table_1 (before)

| application      |    source       |
| 'CMS,NBC,ABC'    |    'acct'       |
| 'ABC,NBC'        |    'credit'     |
| 'MMA'            |    'savings'    |
| 'CMS'            |     'loan'      |

Table_1 (after)

| application      |    source       |
| 'CMS,NBC,ABC'    |    'acct'       |
| 'ABC,NBC,CMS'    |    'credit'     |
| 'MMA'            |    'savings'    |
| 'CMS'            |     'loan'      |

Comment: please enter sample data and your desired output.

Comment: @MeysamAsadi I have added sample data.

Comment: I was a little confused. Enter the data as a table and plot the output as a table.

Comment: @MeysamAsadi I added before and after table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `case`

for update

```
UPDATE table_1
SET application = CASE WHEN application LIKE '%CMS%' THEN application ELSE CONCAT(application,',CMS') END
WHERE source IN('acct', 'credit', 'mortgage','loan')
```

or only select

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN application LIKE '%CMS%' THEN application ELSE CONCAT(application,',CMS') END AS application,
    source
FROM table_1
WHERE source IN('acct', 'credit', 'mortgage','loan')
```

or all rows

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN application LIKE '%CMS%' THEN application ELSE CONCAT(application,',CMS') END AS application,
    source
FROM table_1
WHERE source IN('acct', 'credit', 'mortgage','loan')

UNION

SELECT *
FROM table_1
WHERE source NOT IN('acct', 'credit', 'mortgage','loan')
```

demo in [*db<>fiddle*](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=5d9cfa48354dc2795326cc3652bccba5)

Comment: I am getting a syntax error. I should have clarified that it is MariaDB  10.2.36 server. Will this work for that?

Comment: I fixed syntax error, there was missing ' in concat. But now it is only querying the selected source columns, it is not concating ',CMS' to application columns.

Comment: see in mariadb : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=cd7179e9b3d630e84a8634ddca424097

Comment: so when I run the query, it is appending CMS correctly. But then after when I query the entire table, changes are not saved? So query works, but changes are not being saved to table...

Comment: query is working but I need it to update table, not just query.